# Visible type application in Haskell : how to bind the type

Tags: haskell, types, type-level-computation

With visible type application, one can specify at which type we "call" a polymorphic value.

This allow to remove values like `Proxy :: Proxy s` just to bind the type `s` when we are a user, we just write `myPolyValue @ s`

But if we are *building* a polymorphic value, is there a way to bind the type at which we are called, apart with an argument of type  `Proxy s` ?

**Example**  I use `VisibleTypeApplication` to force a polymorphic type, but I have no idea on how to bind the type I was binded to, except via a `Proxy s` argument :

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver nightly-2018-12-12 script --package base-unicode-symbols --package unicode-prelude --package constraints
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes,GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts , TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs , FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses , ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs , MultiParamTypeClasses     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes , TypeOperators             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UnicodeSyntax,DataKinds              #-}

module ImplicitConfigurationFirstPart where

import Data.Proxy

data KNat where
  Zero :: KNat
  Twice :: KNat -> KNat
  Succ :: KNat -> KNat
  Pred :: KNat -> KNat

class ReflectNum (s :: KNat) where reflectNum ∷ Num a ⇒ Proxy s -> a
instance                ReflectNum  'Zero      where reflectNum _ = 0
instance ReflectNum s ⇒ ReflectNum ('Pred  s) where reflectNum _ = (reflectNum (Proxy @ s)) - 1
instance ReflectNum s ⇒ ReflectNum ('Succ  s) where reflectNum _ = (reflectNum (Proxy @ s)) + 1
instance ReflectNum s ⇒ ReflectNum ('Twice s) where reflectNum _ = (reflectNum (Proxy @ s)) * 2

reifyIntegral ∷ (Integral a) ⇒ a → (∀ (s :: KNat). ReflectNum s ⇒ Proxy s -> w) → w
reifyIntegral i k = case quotRem i 2 of
  (0,0)  → k $ Proxy @ 'Zero
  (j,0)  → reifyIntegral j (\(p :: Proxy s) -> let n = reflectNum p in
                                               k $ Proxy @ ('Twice s) )
  (j,1)  → reifyIntegral j (\(_ :: Proxy s) -> k $ Proxy @ ('Succ('Twice s)))
  (j,-1) → reifyIntegral j (\(_ :: Proxy s) -> k $ Proxy @ ('Pred('Twice s)))
```

**Attempt1** 
In this example, the the first case at the `Zero` index works fine.

But the second one can't prove that `'Twice s` is part of `ReflectNum`. It should though, as `s` at which k1 will be applied at, verifies `ReflectNum`, so that `'Twice s` verifies it, and `k`, being polymorphic in `s` provided we have a proof of `ReflectNum s`, can be called.

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes,GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE  TypeFamilies, KindSignatures, FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications, FunctionalDependencies, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables , GADTs, MultiParamTypeClasses, RankNTypes                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, UnicodeSyntax, DataKinds              #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableSuperClasses    #-}
module ImplicitConfigurationFirstPart where

import Data.Proxy

data KNat where
  Zero :: KNat
  Twice :: KNat -> KNat

class ReflectNum (s :: KNat) where reflectNum ∷ Num a ⇒ Proxy s -> a
instance                ReflectNum  'Zero      where reflectNum _ = 0
instance ReflectNum s ⇒ ReflectNum ('Twice s)  where reflectNum _ = (reflectNum (Proxy @ s)) * 2

reifyIntegral2 ∷ forall a w. (Integral a) ⇒ a → (∀ (s :: KNat). ReflectNum s ⇒ w) → w
reifyIntegral2 i k = case quotRem i 2 of
  (0,0)  → k @ 'Zero
  (j,0)  → reifyIntegral2 j k1

  where k1 :: forall (s :: KNat). ReflectNum s ⇒ w
        k1 = k @ ('Twice s)
```

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example of something you would like to rewrite using `TypeApplications`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But if we are *building* a polymorphic value, is there a way to bind the type at which we are called, apart with an argument of type `Proxy s`?

If I understand correctly, what you mean by this is that you wish to define a polymorphic binding that *accepts* a type argument, which is intended to be supplied using visible type application. The answer to that question is to use `forall`.

If you have some function `f` written using `Proxy s`, such as

```
f :: Proxy s -> X -> Y
```

then you can eliminate the `Proxy` argument by enabling `AllowAmbiguousTypes` and `ScopedTypeVariables` and using an explicit `forall` instead:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
f :: forall s. X -> Y
```

The `s` type variable will be bound within the body of `f`.

Comment: I guess that's another problem, even though it stands in the way of getting rid of those `Proxy`